# jquery: drawing and erasing border on focus and blur on any child elements of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a div which can have many (not less then 5) child elements (mostly they are `div`, `table` and `img`). I want to draw border (e.g. with `jquery.css` method) when a user clicked on any child element of that div. It can be easily done with something like

```
$div.click(function() {
    //drawing frame here
});
```

Removing frame on click outside is much more harder. Of cause I can handle deselecting on click event thrown by any other div or body. But... maybe there's more elegant solution?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `.on('focusin')` and `.on('focusout')` events to handle that.

More info: [focusin](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/), [focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) and [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/);

Comment: should I import something more rather than jquery to make function `.on` accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Try using function [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) the surrounding div

Example: 
HTML:

```
<div id="test">
    <div><p>Hallo</p></<div>
        <img src="not found" alt="not found">
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$('#test').on('click', '*', function(){

    $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
return false;
});
```

Fiddler: http://fiddle.jshell.net/